# How do I search for a sequence of non-brackets with grep?

Tags: regex, grep, brackets

I have a file called `test` with this single line:

```
[word space](test words)
```

when I `grep -ho "[^a]*" test`, looking for sequences of non-`a` characters I get

```
[word sp
ce](test words)
```

which is exactly what I expect.

But when I `grep -ho "[^\]]*" test`, trying to search for sequences of non-closing-bracket characters, I get

```
[
w
o
r
d

s
p
a
c
e]
(
t
e
s
t

w
o
r
d
s
)
```

instead of the expected

```
[word space
(test words)
```

I have no idea what's causing this. Why is it matching bracket characters? Why is every character on its own line? Why is it so different from `grep -ho "[^a]*" test`? I thought `\]` would look for a literal `]`, and that's indeed what it seems when I do a `grep -ho '\]' test`. I'm completely lost.

**EDIT AND SOLUTION:**

Turns out my mistake was assuming I had to escape the bracket in the group. A simple `grep -ho "[^]]*" test` solves this.

Comment: What is the expected output from the second `grep`? Is it `grep -ho '[^]]*' test` you are after?

Comment: Oh my goodness that works! I was so stuck on the idea that I had to escape the `]`. I didn't know you didn't have to do that after a `[^`.

Comment: Great that it worked out! If you update your question to show the expected output, you can also write an answer to your own question about how to solve the problem. It may help someone else in the future.